# Convert byte array into single flat byte value

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I have the following array

---

```
byte[] SendBuff = new byte[262];
SendBuff[0] = 0x82;
SendBuff[1] = 0xD2;
SendBuff[2] = 0x00;
SendBuff[3] = Convert.ToByte(tAdd.Text.Substring(0, 2),16);
SendBuff[4] = Convert.ToByte(tLen.Text.Substring(0, 2),16);
```

I have the following function to pass data to;

---

```
SCardTransmit(hCard, ref sIO,ref SendBuff[0],SendBuffLen, ref sIO,ref RecvBuff[0],ref RecvBuffLen);

 @param1 (int)
 @param2 (ModWinsCard.SCARD_IO_REQUEST)
 @param3 (buyte[])
 @param4 (int)
 @param5 (ModWinsCard.SCARD_IO_REQUEST)
 @param6 (buyte[])
 @param7 (int)
```

am wondering how to pass all the array data into the function's third parameter as a single byte such that 
SendBuff[0]=combination of SendBuff[0],SendBuff[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_card_application_protocol_data_unit),SendBuff[2],SendBuff[3] bytes

---

Am also wondering how to convert the string like "88 00 1A 31 31 31" to byte and store it into SendBuff[0]

I know this may sound a repetition but i have fail to find a solution that might work for me. 
Some one out there please help me out , am stack on this.
Thanks in advance

---

Explainations

---

Am developing for smart card and sending a command to the card reader but need the command([APDU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_card_application_protocol_data_unit)) to have the following string a 
4-byte header (CLA, INS, P1, P2) eg "88 D2 00 01 02"

This command is passed to the function mentioned above through param3 of the function as a byte. So am wondering how to pass that command to that param3.Thanks, hope this explanation helps.

Comment: You can't turn 4 bytes into 1 byte, at least not in a simple way to get the 4 bytes back.  Can you explain what you are trying to do in more detail?

Answer (score 5):

Making these assumptions:

1. The SCardTransmit method you have listed, is not the declaration of the method, but the code you're actually using to call it.
2. You give us the types of variables you're using to call the method in the list of @param1-7 items.

If the third parameter is a byte[] (byte array) then you shouldn't be passing in SendBuff[0]. That is actually just passing in a single byte, the one located at index 0. You want to send the entire array. Therefore, your calling code would be:

```
SCardTransmit(hCard, ref sIO, ref SendBuff, SendBuffLen, ref sIO, ref RecvBuff, ref RecvBuffLen);
```

**Note**: I took the liberty of doing the same thing I did to SendBuff to RecvBuff.

---

Your second question, about converting a string to bytes, it looks like you're doing it with `Convert.ToByte(tAdd.Text.Substring(0, 2),16);`.

What you would want is a loop that converted it. You can split the string by the space character into an array of sub-strings that you can iterate over and convert each byte. Here is the code to do that:

```
string stringOfBytes = "88 00 1A 31 31 31";
string[] stringBytes = stringOfBytes.Split(' ');
byte[] outputBytes = new byte[stringBytes.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < stringBytes.Length; i++)
{
    outputBytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(stringBytes[i], 16);
}
```

Comment: if i convert the third parameter from ref SendBuff[0] to SendBuff, it makes an error that "Argument3:cannot convert from ref byte[] to ref byte". The function and using is defined by the [WinScard API](http://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/api/winscard_8h.html)

Comment: @HillaryNamanya So do you just need to call the SCardTransmit function multiple times (once per byte)?

Comment: @StevenDoggart No i need to call it only one and send a full APDU command to the card reader which forwards it to the smart card. The full command like 

88 D2 00 01 02

but in bytes.Thanks

Comment: It may be working as is, are you sure it's not? What is the experience? By passing ref SendBuff[0] and a length of bytes, the backing C++ code can access all of the bytes. ref SendBuff[0] actually passes reference to the byte itself, in  memory, not a copy (as non-ref SendBuff[0]) would.

Can we see your calling code? What is in the SendBuffLen variable.

Answer (score 3):

Your signature for SCardTransmit is incorrect. From pinvoke.net, you can see the proper signature, as well as sample code on how to use it: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winscard/SCardTransmit.html\

```
[DllImport("winscard.dll")]
public static extern int SCardTransmit(int hCard, ref SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioSendRequest, ref byte SendBuff, int SendBuffLen, ref SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioRecvRequest,
        ref byte RecvBuff, ref int RecvBuffLen);
```

For your request, then, you'd call the function with something like this (assume _hCard is a reference to the return from a call to `SCardConnect` (note this discards the returned value):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SCARD_IO_REQUEST
{
   internal uint dwProtocol;
   internal int cbPciLength;
}

SCARD_IO_REQUEST request = new SCARD_IO_REQUEST();
request.dwProtocol = 1; // This is SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1, sub with whatever protocol you're using
request.cbPciLength = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SCARD_IO_REQUEST));

SCardTransmit(_hCard, ref request, ref SendBuff, SendBuff.Length, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

More information on the native call is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and you can use pinvoke.net to get more help on other, similar functions.

Comment: You're welcome. Were you able to figure it out based on this? Do you need further help?